# Best design pattern for calculated values on a subclass?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, calculated-field

Say I have two types:

```
ClassA
{
    int ValueA;
    int CalculatedA;
}

ClassB
{
    int ValueA;
    int CalculatedA;

    int ValueB;
    int CalculatedB;
}
```

`CalculatedB` requires `ValueA` as well as `ValueB`. I'm trying to decide the best pattern to implement this.

**Option 1:** Subclass `ClassA` and add the extra values. Have a common `Update()` method that is overridden in the subclass. This is simple code in the model, but the code to create these classes needs to know which to create in advance, and any code that iterates over a list of these types needs to do type checking to deal with the extra fields.

**Option 2:** Have the extra properties in a separate class, and have the update code for `CalculatedB` there. The issue with this is that `ClassB` then needs some way of knowing when `ValueA` is updated, and I was hoping to not have to implement something like `INotifyPropertyChanged` on these classes. Another way to do this is to have some sort of public Update method on the extra properties class, and have the main class call that method when `ValueA` is updated. Also not desirable.

**Option 3:** Just have `ClassB` with `ValueB` and `CalculatedB` being nullable types. Pass.

Are there any more? Which would you choose?

Comment: I am not a dot net guy. Is there is any possibility of using friend kind of thing here ?

Comment: While friend would help, it's still the same problem as making an internal method or setter public, just that public is a smaller set.

Answer (score 1):

If ClassB is not related to ClassA, then subclassing is not a good method. BTW, in .Net we normally don't expose public fields, but public properties (assume C#)

```
public class ClassA{
    public int ValueA {get;set;}
    //...
}
```

Since ClassB.CalculateB is heavily rely on ValueA, why not just calculate the value on the fly, so you don't have to worry about property changing.

```
public class ClassB {
    public int ValueB {get;set;}
    public int getCalculateB(ClassA a){
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: The classes are related. But otherwise a good point. Also I am using properties I was just too lazy to write the Get;Set; part in the question.

Comment: If you think classB is good to inherit classA, then to avoid the problem you mention in option 1, you might consider: redesign the way it get calculate value and use factory class / method to construct the classes.